# Как построить коррелляционный график на основании текста?

Tags: статический-анализ

Изучение корреляционной взаимосвязи между уровнем пролактина с клиническими, гормональными, гистологическими, молекулярными подтипами и иммуногистохимическими показателями выявило

- положительную корреляцию

  - с масталгией (r=0,71),
  - Ki-67 (r=0,6),
  - HER2/neu (r=0,7),
  - метастазами (r=0,56),
  - эстрадиолом (0,63),
  - инвазивно-протоковым раком (r=0,6),
  - аденокарциномой (r=0,5)
- и отрицательную корреляцию

  - с рецепторами ER (-0,67) и PR (-0,59),
  - также, папиллярным раком (r-0,78),
  - дольковым раком in situ, внутрипротоковым раком in situ (r-0,69) и (r-0,65) соответственно,

с достоверностью p=0,001.

Важен рисунок, который я должна вставить как картинку.

Comment: Ничего не понятно, что вам нужно. Кажется вы ошиблись в направлении мысли - обычно такой текст пишут на основе графика ..

Comment: Если вам нужно для объяснения вопроса вставить график, то вставьте его в вопрос. Пока не совсем понятно, что вам нужно. Хотелось бы более детального описания вопроса.

Answer (score 1):

Может быть, вы хотите что-то такое
(код в Питоне, использован модуль `Matplotlib`):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = ("масталгия", "Ki-67", "метастазы", "HER2/neu", "эстрадиол", 
     "инвазивно-протоковый рак", "аденокарцином", "рецептор ER", 
     "рецептор PR", "папиллярный рак", "дольковый рак", 
     "внутрипротоковый рак")
r = .71, .6, .7, .56, .63, .6, .5, -.67, -.59, -.78, -.69, -.65

plt.barh(x, r)
plt.title("Коррелационные связы")
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]